# Blender Geometry Nodes Instances only partially

Tags: instances, geometry-nodes

how can i make the instances with Geometry Nodes only partially in Rings like on the Plant in the Picture? Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this node setup and play with the multiply and the less than value:

[image]

[image]

---

update: with "height" filter:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :))

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: One additional question: Can i make it somehow that it´s only scattered above a certain height?

Comment: Of course. Just use that z value with math node „greater than“ and plug that result to a Boolean math „and“ note and that result in selection. The result of the less than node plug into the second „and“ input.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I don't really check it.. Could you possibly send me a screenshot?

Comment: i updated my answer. Please do not ask more/further question in comments. nobody will find these questions. So please open another questions for further/more questions so everybody can learn from it. You can ask as many questions as you like. Thank you.

Comment: Yes i will and thank you very much! Geometry Nodes are so powerful!